# The [libgdx] tag should syntax highlight for Java

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

[libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libgdx) is known primarily as a Java game framework. Although Scala and Kotlin work with it when it's not being used with GWT, the majority of incoming questions have Java code in them. All of libGDX's documentation is in Java, so newcomers are mostly using Java with it. I've monitored the tag for several years and have never seen a question with Scala code, and all the questions with Kotlin code have also been tagged [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin).

highlight.js already seems to be able to properly highlight code blocks of either Kotlin or Java in a question tagged with both [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), so I don't think it will cause a problem with old questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not generally apply syntax highlighting hints to *library* tags. There is almost never a case where someone should be asking a question with a library tag that does not also include a language tag. The language tag is necessary to tell the answerers what language the asker is using and therefore expecting answers to be written in. Since the language tag has a syntax-highlighting hint applied to it, this hint will dominate, and the question will have the appropriate syntax highlighting.

If a question is tagged [libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libgdx), is using Java, and is not correctly highlighted, then fix it by applying the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag.